# How to search a JSON object for a specific string within the object using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api

I am retrieving JSON objects from an API using AJAX calls in jQuery.  This is an example object that I am getting back:

```
  ...
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "normalized": [
      {
        "from": "star trek",
        "to": "Star trek"
      }
    ],
    "pages": {
      "1048985": {
        "pageid": 1048985,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Star trek",
        "extract": "<ul><li><b>From other capitalisation</b>: This is a redirect from a title with another method of capitalisation. It leads to the title in accordance with the Wikipedia naming conventions for capitalisation, or it leads to a title that is associated in some way with the conventional capitalisation of this redirect title. This may help writing, searching and international language issues.\n<ul><li>If this redirect is an incorrect capitalisation, then {{R from miscapitalisation}} should be used <i>instead</i>, and pages that use this link should be updated to link <i>directly</i> to the target. Miscapitisations can be tagged in <i>any namespace</i>.</li>\n<li>Use this rcat to tag <i>only</i> mainspace redirects; when other capitalisations are in other namespaces, use {{R from modification}} <i>instead</i>.</li>\n</ul></li>\n</ul>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have another JSON object coming back that looks like this:

```
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "normalized": [
      {
        "from": "set",
        "to": "Set"
      }
    ],
    "pages": {
      "454886": {
        "pageid": 454886,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Set",
        "extract": "<p><b>Set</b> or <b>The Set</b> may refer to:</p>\n\n"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I am attempting to do is search these objects for specific strings in order to perform logic on the results to retrieve the data I am actually looking for.  In the first example, I want to find 'From other capitalisation' in the "extract" value, and in the second example, I want to find 'may refer to:'.

Is there a way to search a specific JSON object for a specific string and return whether that string is present or not?

Comment: So, do you everytime need different strings?

Comment: not really.  These are the only two strings that I need to search for.  Both of these strings will trigger different logic on the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific case, I would do something like this

```
function searchResponse(response, query){

  // loop through the objects keys which appear to be different page numbers
  for (const pageNum in response.pages){
    // reference the actual page object
    const page = response.pages[pageNum];


    // test the extract against the query.         
    if (page.extract.indexOf(query) !== -1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Then you'd invoke the function on each response with whatever search term you are looking for. A result of `true` would mean that the response contained the query. However, this would not work if the api returned multiple pages because it would search through each page and `return true` if ANY of the pages contained the `query`, which might not be the desired results.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know why indexOf didn't come to me for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you. Using plain javascript to iterate over keys and find the required object.

```js
var obj = {
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "normalized": [{
      "from": "set",
      "to": "Set"
    }],
    "pages": {
      "454886": {
        "pageid": 454886,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Set",
        "extract": "<p><b>Set</b> or <b>The Set</b> may refer to:</p>\n\n"
      }
    }
  }
 };

var searchStr = " may refer to";
var results = [];
Object.keys(obj.query.pages).forEach(function(key) {
  if (obj.query.pages[key].extract.includes(searchStr)) {
    results.push(obj.query.pages[key].extract);
  }
});

results.forEach(function(res){ console.log(res); });
```

Comment: I hadn't considered includes as an option.  Does that only work for testing strings in jQuery or would that work for testing other data types as well?

Comment: `includes` works on any `String` but it is ES2015 and might not be supported on all browsers yet.

Comment: @AustinEzell you can use polyfill for that. But just for this task using jquery will be overkill I guess.